# Sum of two numbers Python

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code, but the Spyder keeps saying there is an `indexError` of `list index out of range` for `a = int(tokens[0])`. Please advise.

```
import sys

input_ = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input_.split()

a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])

print(a+b)
```

The below also works, but I see someone running the above code in Linux and worked, and I am on windows, wondering what is the cause of the above not running properly. Thanks all!

```
def sum_of_two_digits(first_digit, second_digit):
    return first_digit + second_digit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    print(sum_of_two_digits(a, b))
```

Comment: "list index out of range" means that the list does not contain a `0`th element.  In other words, the list is empty.  Try `print(input_)` and see if the result is what you expect.

Comment: Tip: `sum_of_two_digits` is just a less useful version of the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

Answer (score 0):

To prove you're getting the input you expect, you can `print(len(tokens))` or simply `print(input_)`. But suffice to say this is not a Linux/Windows issue. Rather, your `tokens` variable is empty by the time you index into it (`tokens[0]`).

You're not getting anything into the `input_` value. This may be because you're using `read()` and are inputing the values in an unexpected way (I am guessing?). `input()` will probably serve you better - note that the 'Linux' version you refer to uses `input()`. `read()` will block until you send an escape sequence, though that probably has happened if you get to the list index error.